# SKPhysicsBody.BodyWithPolygonFromPath returns null

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, sprite-kit

I'm trying to set the PhysicsBody of an `SKSpriteNode` object using an `SKPhysicsBody` created from a polygon path (a `CGPath` object).
I have verified that the path I'm using is valid by creating an `SKShapeNode` using the path and adding it as a child of the sprite (see screenshot).

However, when I try to create the `SKPhysicsBody` object, the `BodyWithPolygonFromPath` method returns NULL.
The method does not throw an exception, it just returns NULL.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

While exceptions do exists in Objective-C but they are not commonly used (like in .NET). Bindings can provide some extra checks (e.g. against null parameters, avoiding crashes) but some condition cannot be duplicated (e.g. when would a path be considered invalid ?)

In general you'll find that Apple provides an API that:

- returns an `NSError` instance (either as a return value or, more commonly, as an `out` parameter); or
- returns `null` (`nil` in Objective-C) when its input (or context) is invalid. This is very common for `init*` selectors (and that's not something a .NET developer would think of, i.e. having a .ctor return `null`); or
- in a few cases, an `NSException` is thrown.

In some cases you will get some logs (see Console.app for the iOS Simulator or Xcode's organizer for devices) that will give you clues about what went wrong. Often you won't get anything... YMMV.

In the later case you should try to backtrace your steps, e.g. how was your `path` created ? could it be empty ? does some of it's properties looks weird in the watch window ? ...

It might also prove useful to give us some code to duplicate the issue (or at least see how you create the `path). Other people likely encountered the same issue before... but might not be able to tell/remember without additional details.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I haven't checked Console.app yet, will do that at the first opportunity today. The path was created with an online generator and it does work on SKShapeNode object, so that makes me think it's a valid path.

Comment: It could be context specific. I've seen SpriteKit requiring some operations to be done in a certain order, i.e. re-ordering the code solve issues (and crashes). But before going too far first make sure it follow Apple's documented requirement: **A convex polygonal path with counterclockwise winding and no self intersections. The points are specified relative to the owning node’s origin.**

Answer (score 1):

I tried to output some details to the Visual Studio debug console and suddenly noticed that Xamarin/Mono outputs an error message there from the `SKPhysicsBody` object:

> SKPhysicsBody: Error attempting to create polygon with 18 vertices,
>   maximum is 12

So the problem was that my polygon was too complex.
I've simplified it to 12 vertices and it works now!